# Custom JSON Ajax loop that changes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm making an Ajax JSON call to an API with a variable `n`.

The higher the variable and depending on the user, the more results are called.

If nothing is returned, the returned JSON value `response` is "Nothing found".

I am trying to code a script where, if nothing is returned, the variable `n` increases by 5 and the code loops until a response is received which contains results.

How can this be achieved?

Relevant code:

```
var n=5;

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  url: 'http://www.URL.com/API.php?var='+n,
  success: function (data, status) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {      
      //Do stuff here
    });
  }
});
```

Example response:

```
if(item.response=="Nothing Found"){
  n=n+5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function sendRequest(n) {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
     url: 'http://www.URL.com/API.php?var='+n,
     success: function (data, status) {
          //i assume that your items have property response which you want to check 
          //if I'm wrong then it is just "if (data.response === ...)"
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {                         
               if (item.response === "Nothing found") {
                   sendRequest(n + 5);
               };
               else {
                  //process response
               }
          });
     }
   });
};

sendRequest(5);
```

Comment: This is perfect and brilliantly helpful. Thank you a hundred times!